# How to send user from nodemailer reset password mail to my react native app

Tags: node.js, react-native, nodemailer

i build full functions that worked and send emil to user when he "forgot password",its worked perfect on postMan, now the problem is when i clicked on the email url is direct me to "Cannot GET /resetpassword/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCeyJfaWQiOiI1ZmQ5ZmFmZjFjODA2YTgyMjZjMTQ5YmUiLCJp"

if i was do that for web app its work, but how can i redirect to open my app and show the screen for reset password?

```js
exports.sendEmail = emailData => {
    const transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        requireTLS: true,
        auth: {
            user: "roeigr7@gmail.com",
            pass: "iaoqymixqarajkbv",
        },
    });
    return transporter.sendMail(emailData);
};
```

and the data send to:

```js
const emailData = {
    from: "noreply@Lior.com",
    to: email,
    subject: "Password Reset Instructions",
    text: `Please use the following link to reset your password: ${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/resetpassword/${token}`,
    html: `<p>Please use the following link to reset your password:</p> <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/resetpassword/${token}</p>`,
```

---------reset password FUNCTION:

```
exports.resetPassword = (req, res) => {
const { resetPassword, newPassword } = req.body;

User.findOne({ resetPassword }, (err, user) => {
    // if err or no user
    if (err || !user)
        return res.status("401").json({
            error: "Invalid Link!",
        });

    const updatedFields = {
        password: newPassword,
        resetPassword: "",
    };

    user = _.extend(user, updatedFields);
    user.updated = Date.now();

    user.save((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: err,
            });
        }
        res.json({
            message: `סיסמא שונתה בהצלחה`,
        });
    });
});
 };`
```

--------- resetPassword component:

```
const resetPassword = async resetInfo => {
try {
    const response = await indexApi.put("resetPassword", {
        resetInfo,
    });
    console.log("forgot password response: ", response);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response.data.error);
}
  };
const resetPassModal = () => {
return (
    <View style={{ marginVertical: 30 }}>
        <Text onPress={resetPassword} style={styles.titletext}>
            reset
        </Text>
```

Comment: could you tell me, what is `${process.env.CLIENT_URL}`?

Comment: CLIENT_URL=http://localhost:3000
ok so i now i see that is direct to the server, BUT something wrong with the authrized to see page Cannot GET /resetpassword/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZmQ5

Comment: please i need help .. i'm getting involved with how to direct user to page after he clicked on the email :(((((((((

Comment: `localhost:3000/resetpassword/${token}` this is just web url. if you want redirect to app, find [`mobile deep linking`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_deep_linking). ex) `fb://profile/33138223345`- this facebook wiki profile deep link

Comment: What is the authentication failure question? It seems that the current question has been modified. New questions must be new.

Comment: can you help me step by step with that? what i need to do insted of localhost:3000/

Comment: its the same question... my problem is that i get after clicked on the email: Cannot GET /resetpassword/eyJhbGciOiJIUz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226285/discussion-between-roei-grinshpan-and-myeongkil-kim).